# segmentation fault while writting packet to a pcap file

Tags: c++, c, pcap, libpcap

I am trying to write the output packets from our application to a pcap file using pcap library but I am getting segmentation fault when I call pcap_dump

I have tried to write the following small program which basically reproduces my problem

```
int main()
{    
     pcap_t *m_p;
     pcap_dumper_t *m_pd;
     m_p = pcap_open_dead ( DLT_RAW, 65535 );

     m_pd = pcap_dump_open ( m_p, ( char * ) "abc.pcap" );

     char a[100] = "\0";
     strcpy(a,"name");
     struct pcap_pkthdr p;
     p.caplen = strlen(a) + 1;
     p.len = p.caplen;

     pcap_dump ( ( u_char * ) m_p, &p, ( u_char * )  a );

     pcap_close(m_p);
     pcap_dump_close(m_pd);

     return 0;        
}
```

Following is the bt of the core that I am getting

```
gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f74e6d0df5d in fwrite () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f74e77c9bfd in pcap_dump () from /usr/lib64/libpcap.so.1
#2  0x000000000040084e in main () at mypacp.cc:17
```

Can some one tell me what am I missing.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing `m_pd`, not `m_p` to the first argument of pcap_dump?

Comment: thanks a lot :) that was a really silly oversight

Comment: kind of makes me wonder the point of having type system at all if something like this isn't getting caught at compile-time.

Comment: In C, callbacks ("the severely impoverished man's closures" :-)) and the type system don't always work very well together.  `pcap_dump()`s function signature matches what `pcap_loop()` and `pcap_dispatch()` expect of a callback; one argument is the "private data" argument, so that the callback can get whatever information it needs.  It's `char *`, meaning "generic pointer"; sadly, this allows a *particular* callback to be passed the wrong type of argument without the compiler checking it.